# Add new Control to Customizer to modify Headings (h1, h2, h3...) Color

Tags: customization, theme-customizer

I'm trying to add a custom Control to change all the Headings color on my site without hardcoding it into my `style.css`

Is there a sample code that I can use as a reference to implement this using my Child Theme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as far as I know there is no Wordpress Standard Control in the Theme Customizer for a Color Picker. But you can add one with a new Class. Paul underwood made a wonderful tutorial for adding Custom Controls  [here](https://paulund.co.uk/creating-your-own-theme-customiser-custom-controls)!   And gave examples containing a color picker on [github](https://github.com/paulund/wordpress-theme-customizer-custom-controls/blob/master/theme-customizer-demo.php). (NOTE: Please note of the important below comment from WestonRuter, there is now a Color Picker Control in WP).
A simpler approach could be to create a text-field and put your hex-value into it. Threre for you have to create a setting and control in your functions.php. The code in functions.php might looks like the following:

```
function yourtheme_customize_register($wp_customize) {
//Add new Section for Theme
    $wp_customize->add_section('yourtheme_theme_section', array(
        'title' => __('yourtheme Settings', 'yourtheme'),
       'priority' => 30,
    ));


//  Add new Setting
    $wp_customize->add_setting('headings_color', array(
        'default' => __('Please enter a Quote in Customizer', 'yourtheme'),
    ));

// Add new Control
    $wp_customize->add_control('headings_color_control', array(
        'label' => __('hex color', 'yourtheme'),
        'section' => 'your_theme_section',
        'settings' => 'headings_color',
        'type' => 'text',
    ));
add_action('customize_register', 'yourtheme_customize_register');
```

You can use the Value from Customizer in your template files (e.g. header.php) with the get_theme_mod() function. e.g.

```
 <style> h1, h2, h3 {color: <?php echo get_theme_mod('headings_color')  ;?>;}</style>
```

Hope that will help you.

Comment: Thanks! Your suggestion solved my problem. Anyone interested can view my complete codes including “Color Picker” from [github](https://gist.github.com/mdazmir/6225d239de57a8d59057cdfe4ec26a9c)

Comment: @Friedrich: So there is in fact a standard control for color picker control in core (`WP_Customize_Color_Control`). This is used for managing background color and header text color, among other theme options. I highly recommend re-using it instead of creating a custom hex control. You can see usage here: https://github.com/WordPress/twentysixteen/blob/6f1f3af/inc/customizer.php#L144-L147

Comment: @WestonRuter: Forgot to mention within my first comment that I'm using the standard control for color picker within my codes. You can view my implementation here: [github](https://gist.github.com/mdazmir/6225d239de57a8d59057cdfe4ec26a9c)